# react-native and expo default options language issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, internationalization, expo, i18next

I am working on a react-native application based on expo.

My problem is that I am trying to find a solution to make the default options on inputs : `paste` `cut` `select` `select all`...
and the default actions on the camera: `take picture`... uses the default language of the mobile phone and not all the time English.

is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to change the language of your phone and ABSOLUTELY reboot so it can work.